# How to set up roster in MongooseIM

Tags: mongoose-im

Is it possible to lock roster modification to certain group? Ejabberd enables it like:

```
access_rules:
  roster:
    - allow: admin
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible at this moment in MongooseIM.